# reconstruct a function by given values using Fourier series or other algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, function, fft

I was curious what would be an efficient way for reconstructing a function by having some continuous values (say I have y-values for x between [0,10] (x is an integer and the corresponding decimal y-values are between [0,1])) of it available and if it is possible to set a precision for the algorithm used to get an arbitrary approximation.

I came across the possibility to reconstruct such functions using Fourier series but am very uncertain on how to implement that in C# on my own. The purpose is to learn by doing rather than using already available libraries. Any other suggestions on how to (approximately) build up a function are welcome as well. For creating functions during runtime I was thinking of meta-programming (with `Expression`s).

**Edit:** For Fourier series, I found a related question plus [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5447944/1785141). However, the solution provided is in Mathematica and uses its library.

Comment: Do you have an idea on how the points are distributed (linear, polynomial, spline)?

Comment: "(say I have y-values for x between [0,10])" - Are these discrete values (for example, is x an int)?

Comment: @mbeckish: Yes, x is in integer and y is between [0..1] in my case.

Comment: @AhmedKRAIEM: I guess it's a spline-curve then?

Comment: If you are looking to fit these points to a periodic function, then you probably want [DFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform).  Note that this isn't the only option.  You could also fit these points to a polynomial, for example.

Comment: I checked out the DFT and it seems to be a viable way. [This anser](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11976699/1785141) computes the DFT but yields values instead of a function description. How could I build up a function from these values (I cannot comprehend the relation).

Comment: That answer computes each X_k from [this equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#equation_Eq.1) and stores them in an array.  The function you want to build is the [inverse DFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#equation_Eq.2), which uses the previous results to re-compute any of the original samples.  If you use this function to predict values beyond  the original sample set, they will just be a repeat of the original samples (because DFT fits your samples to a *periodic* function).

Comment: Ok, if I got it right, the FFT would be able to fit my samples into a non-periodic function and its inverse function (IFFT) allows to predict values outside the original sample-set?

Comment: @Quickie007 - No, all Fourier transforms are periodic functions. Basically, the transform computes the frequency, amplitude, and phase of a set of sine waves which, when added together, would intersect your samples.

Answer (score 1):

A Fourier series won't reconstruct a function from a finite length of samples (unless the samples happen to be from an exact integer multiple number of periods of a known pure periodic function or signal).  It will only approximate a function convolved with the transform of the data window, and using a series of sine and cosine functions that may or may not be related to the "true" unwindowed function or signal.  Deconvolving the convolution function (usually a periodic Sinc function) is non-trivial, but required to estimate possible candidate waveforms that can be extended beyond the data window.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification. It appears to me that using Fourier in any variation cannot answer the original question given the samples of input data. Are you aware of other techniques that allow for approximate reconstructions?

Comment: @Quickie007 - There are an infinite number of functions that can fit any fixed number of data samples, yet yield different results once you go beyond those samples.  Typically, you should know what kind of function you expect the data to follow (linear, quadratic, etc.), and then you use a curve fitting technique to find the parameters for that function.